# Browsers removing table elements

Tags: html, browser

Where to start with this one, haven't had to ask an HTML question in over 15 years, and even with several search's on google, as well as a search here on SO, I have found absolutely zero on this issue. Just to note I ran into this on both Chrome and Firefox, and really I only need it to work in Chrome. Only checked Firefox as this issue is so ridiculous that I needed to make sure I wasn't seeing things.

I am building a fairly complex web app, one of the features allows the user to view some of the tables in the database. The 2 tables, that they can view, each have 10's of thousands of records (rows). Now, I am making it so that as they scroll it will load (and unload) more records, but, the more records I can load in one shot the better. Tables were made for displaying tabular data, but, as most here know, not large quantities of it (kind of defeats their purpose). So I am experimenting with how to load (render) larger numbers of rows, faster.

My first experiment was to replace each `<td>` in the table with a `<div>`.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>data</div>
                <div>data</div>
                <div>data</div>
                <!-- ect -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

The results, a disaster. The `<table>` `<tbody>` `<tr>` and `<td>` tags have been stripped out by the browsers. And when you have css that is `#someid table div {}` you really have a mess.

I guess ultimately I will have to either go with a pure `<table>` or pure `<div>` solution. But I would like to at least try a mixed solution. I am hoping there is some little thing I am unaware of that will remedy this very horrible behavior by Firefox and Chrome. This kind of reminds me of some of the stupid stuff that IE pulled in the past, speaking of which, if felt like checking I'd be willing to bet IE has this issue also.

Comment: You probably have an unclosed tag somewhere. You could validate your generated HTML with a validator. There’s no way we can reproduce this issue without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It all worked as a table prior to converting some parts to divs. But, just in case I went and checked and all tags are closed. As for an example, its all generated dynamically, that is a lot of code. But you did get me thinking. The table is loaded via xhr. So I looked at the response from the server and it has the table tags still intact. But they are not being rendered on screen. One would think a problem with my javascript, but then explain why there is no problem rendering it when it is pure table???

Comment: Funny just tested my example and it works, I wonder if it has to do with the quantity of rows causing the browser to make adjustments???

Comment: If it’s generated dynamically, you can still simply view the page source of the generated page and copy-paste that into an HTML validator.

Comment: I think I am ditching the tables all together now. Just completed a few tests  of a pure div solution, using `inline-block` and `float`, and the load and render times were reduced better than 60% as compared to the pure table load times. It helps that the loaded files lost about 10% of their size by going with divs, but it the rendering side that has seen the biggest improvement. Not really sure why tables are even still in the HTML spec if they are useless for serious display of tabular data.